# Query a table resulting from a SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have an SQL script named c:\test.sql with the following content;

```
select * from sales group by order_id;
```

I want to be able to use that script in another query.

For example:

```
select * from (c:\\test.sql) where rownum <= 100;
```

Note that I already tried the @ and @@ operators. And cannot get the job done via straightforward example because these operators execute a script separately and cannot apply a nested query which is what I need, not nested scripts.

I also do not want to create any objects in the database as intermediate tables and views.

Is that even possible?

I am using is EXAplus version 6.0.5, which [has its own version of @](https://docs.exasol.com/connect_exasol/sql_clients/exaplus_cli/alphabeticallistofexapluscommands/@_and_start.htm), not SQL*Plus.

Comment: I suppose you have to build your query on the fly from the query template and the output of the inner script.

Comment: You have to use joins

Comment: You shouldn't generally create tables on the fly anyway; but that might not be exactly what you mean by 'generate a table'. You probably want a CTE that generates the same data you're creating the table with. It's unclear exactly what the script is doing though. If you include a simplified example of the script we might be able to help.

Comment: Please share your complete query

Comment: I added an example of the sql script to be more specific in my example.

Comment: You may return variables from scripts in sql*plus with the [exit statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188438/sql-oracle-query-a-table-resulting-from-an-sql-script). Perhaps that can help you if you can give back a cursor or sth.

Comment: it really does seem like you want a VIEW in this case.  Is there a compelling reason to not want one?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to remove `;` from your script containing your query, then you need simple script :

```
Select *
From (
@your_script
) 
WHERE rownum <100;
```

Btw, I often use @/@@ for advanced scripting in SQL*Plus, SQLCl or SQLDeveloper:
http://orasql.org/2013/03/29/sqlplus-tips-1/

http://orasql.org/2013/04/17/sqlplus-tips-4-branching-execution/

For example, you can also read script contents using the same approach:

**Reading tmp.sql into substitution variable sfile:**

tmp.sql:

```sql
select 123,456 from dual
```

Example:

```sql
col sfile new_value sfile noprint
select q'[
@tmp.sql
]' sfile from dual;
prompt &sfile
```

Result:

```
SQL> prompt &sfile
select 123,456 from dual
```

Comment: [42000] syntax error, unexpected $undefined [line 3, column 1]. I tried that even before you suggested :D. Did you test it? It is breaking..

Comment: @criticalth - this approach does work in SQL\*Plus, SQLcl and (I think) SQL Developer - your reference to @ and @@ implied you were using one of those. If not please specify which client (and version) you are using in your question. (Might also be helpful to explain why you have the queries in separate scripts, and if it's to use that code in various places, if you've considered defining views or using functions that return result sets?)

Comment: @criticalth is it really oracle rdbms? What database and client do you use? Your error doesn't look like oracle error.

Comment: @AlexPoole the client I am using is EXAplus version 6.0.5.

Comment: @criticalth that's a rather important piece of information. Not many people here will be using EXAplus, and it appears (unsurprisingly) to work differently than the standard Oracle tools we all have.

Comment: btw, I often use @ in sqlplus and sqlcl/sqldeveloper for such things: for example, you can read file into variable using `select q[' \n
  @tmp.sql \n
 ' sfile from dual`: http://orasql.org/2013/03/29/sqlplus-tips-1/ 
http://orasql.org/2013/04/17/sqlplus-tips-4-branching-execution/ (added \n to show new line chars (stackoverflow doesn't allow them in comments)

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the query using an in-line view as follows.

It would not create any intermediary view objects

```
select * 
  from (select order_id 
          from sales 
        group by order_id
       ) 
 where rownum <= 100;
```

Comment: Yes, I know this and I should have clarified that this is NOT what I need. Apologies, my mistake. I am building a huge data program that needs to be executed regularly and I need to build different blocks which at some point come together. I can make the query 5000 rows but it will be difficult to maintain afterwards.